# retrieving data from google maps to use in iOS app

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to create an iOS app, which shows data available in terrain view of Google Maps (peaks, forests etc) within some specific area.  Is it possible to retrieve eg all peaks with their latitudes and longitudes? I went through Google Maps iOS SDK but I didn't find the answer.

My other idea was just to download some database containing european peaks but neither could I found it.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible within the Google Maps API. But I believe the downloadable database at http://www.geonames.org will help you.